# Removing just one inherit permission using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, inheritance, acl

I'm trying to write a script that can remove access rights for just one  (e.g. Everyone) on folders that have inherited permissions in place.

The other inherit permissions should stay intact. I can remove the inherit permissions and then remove access for that group, but inheritance is then broken. I don't want to enable inheritance after this action because of subfolders having no inheritance being broken.

How do I just remove this group without messing with the rest of the permissions?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot (by design) remove an inherited permission, "without messing with the rest of the permissions".

What you *can* do is

1. Disallow inheritance, but preserve already inherited rules
2. Remove/modify the `EVERYONE` ACE after removing inheritance

Like this:

```
$FilePath = "C:\parentFolder\childItem.ext"
$FileACL  = Get-Acl $FilePath

# Remove inheritance but preserve existing entries
$FileACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
Set-Acl $FilePath -AclObject $FileACL

# Retrieve new explicit set of permissions
$FileACL  = Get-Acl $FilePath

# Retrieve "everyone" rule
$EveryoneRule = $FileACL.GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"EVERYONE"}

# Remove it - or modify it and use SetAccessRule() instead
$FileACL.RemoveAccessRule($EveryoneRule)

# Set ACL on file again
Set-Acl $FilePath -AclObject $FileACL
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove groups or users ACE without disabling inheritance, use CACLS *folder* /E /R *group/user*. I know that CACLS is deprecated but I have not found any equivalent when using iCacls or SETACL.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to delete inheritance.

It is possible to just remove this one little mistake. Had the same error and it was successful on a Windows 2016 Fileserver.

I modified the Script from Mathias R. Jessen a bit. If you want to do this just to one Folder, replace "$folders = Get-Childitem" with "$filepath = Get-Item" and only use the commands inside the foreach loop.

Open Powershell as Admin

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\To\Folder" | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($FilePath in $folders)
{
    $FileACL  = Get-Acl $FilePath.FullName
    $EveryoneRule = $FileACL.GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) | Where-Object {$_.AccessControlType -eq "Deny"}
    $FileACL.RemoveAccessRule($EveryoneRule)
    Set-Acl $FilePath.FullName -AclObject $FileACL
}
```